# (Done!) Chapter Uppercase | indentation in section numbering

Tags: line-breaking, chapters, indentation, sections-paragraphs, line

I'm editing this book >>
https://www.overleaf.com/read/dntbyngmsfzs

and I'm having 3 problems:

[image]

1. The top summary I can't get down to 2.5 cm
2. The chapter is not capitalized (uppercase) and IS NOT MAKING THE LINE BREAK =O
3. The indentation of the numbering of sections and subsections is outside the margin and I need it to be aligned (in the image, the numbering "1.1" starts where it is "In the bottom of a poem").

Whoever could give me this help, would be immensely grateful.

Help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: a]

It requires four changes in your document:

In the file **structure.tex**

**(1)** line 274

Replace

```
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}}
```

For

```
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\textcolor{ocre}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{1em}}    %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

**(2)** Line 324

Replace

```
\node[anchor=north west] at (1.1cm,.35cm) {\parbox[t][8cm][t]{6.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\flushleft \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}}};
```

For

```
\node[anchor=north west] at (1.1cm,-2.35cm) {\parbox[t][8cm][t]{6.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\flushleft \printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}}}; %%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

**(3)** Line 325

Replace

```
\draw[anchor=west] (5cm,-9cm) node [rounded corners=20pt,fill=ocre!10!white,text opacity=1,draw=ocre,draw opacity=0,line width=1.5pt,fill opacity=0,inner sep=12pt]{\huge\bfseries\textcolor{black}{\thechapter. #1\strut\makebox[22cm]{}}};
```

For

```
\draw[anchor=west] (2cm,-9cm) node [rounded corners=20pt,fill=ocre!10!white,text opacity=1,draw=ocre,draw opacity=0,line width=1.5pt,fill opacity=0,inner sep=12pt]{\Large\bfseries\textcolor{black}{{\huge\thechapter.} \hspace{1em}\strut\parbox[c]{9cm}{\raggedright \uppercase{#1}}}};%%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

In file **main.tex**

**(4)** Use `\\` to select where you want the line breaks. Otherwise they will be selected by LaTeX.

```
\chapter{Bogotá mi ciudad \\ Utilizarás adecuadamente \\ los conectores lógicos\\ Analizarás una película}
```

like this

[image: d]

Replicate the chapter title in capital letters also in the TOC using

```
\chapter[\uppercase{Bogotá mi ciudad Utilizarás adecuadamente los conectores lógicos  Analizarás una película}]{Bogotá mi ciudad \\ Utilizarás adecuadamente \\ los conectores lógicos \\ Analizarás una película}
```

[image: z]

Comment: Amazing!!!!! Perfect =D Thanks so much